# What is the meanig of かるーく?

Tags: meaning

This is a line of dialogue Yahari anime:

> なので　気晴らしに**かるーく**遊びに誘えたらいいかなっと

I do not understand **かるーく**.

Is that just an elongation of the vowel or a contraction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「かるーく」 is how 「かるく（軽く）」 is sometimes pronounced in informal conversation.

In the sentence in question, 「かるーく」 just means "***a little bit***", "***in an easy or casual manner***", etc.

> "So, I was kinda thinking it'd be cool to casually ask you/him/her/them out for relaxation."

Answer (score 2):

かるーく is the same as かるく, but like this (○○ー○) , sound to be long, that means **really** some. For example:

- 少し → すこーし

but unable to be used is many than able to be used.